# Generating bimodal distributions

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have a problem where I have 5 examples of truncated bimodal distributions between different ranges of (-1.0, +1.0), (-0.18, +0.18), (-0.12, +0.12) and (-0.15, +0.15). The example distributions can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB9mL.jpg).

Please note that for all of the given example bimodal distributions, ***there is no zero values*** within the given distribution! The data distributions have values ranging between the given ranges EXCEPT of ZERO!

I am trying to create a sampling technique which can create random samples by obeying the given bimodal samples in the examples. The samples to be drawn can be of any size/shape/dimension such as 784, 5000, etc.

Any ideas how I can create such truncated bimodal data distributions between intervals 'a' and 'b' or [a, b] (both points are included)!

Thanks!

Comment: There are gazillions of ways to generate such distributions, but these examples are obviously special.  Could you tell us more about what they represent?

Answer (score 1):

A [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with both shape parameters $< 1$ will have a 'bathtub'
shape with modes at the ends.  Modes of a beta *density function* will be of equal height if the two
shape parameters are equal (nearly equal for *samples).*
Beta distributions have support $(0,1).$

Example (using R):

```
set.seed(421)
x = rbeta(2000, .5, .5)
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="BETA(.5, .5)")
  curve(dbeta(x, .5,.5), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Smaller shape parameters put less probability in the middle.

```
set.seed(422)
x = rbeta(2000, .2, .2)
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="BETA(.5, .5)")
  curve(dbeta(x, .2,.2), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

You can transform by a linear function to get bivariate data in intervals other than $(0,1).$

```
y = 3*x + 2
hist(y, prob=2, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

*Note:* All samples above are of size $n=2000.$ Larger samples tend to give histograms that follow the population density curve more closely. Smaller samples can give
histograms with more 'raggedy' profiles.

[image]